# Creating Custom ChangePassword - .net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

little help on how I can create my own `changepassword`? The challenge is with `passwordhashing`. Tried with some examples found on stack but did not work.

This is my code:

```
        var currentPassword = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(changePassword.CurrentPassword);
        ApplicationUser user = (from x in _context.AspNetUsers
                                where x.Id == changePassword.UserId && x.PasswordHash == currentPassword
                                select new ApplicationUser()
                                {
                                    FirstName = x.FirstName,
                                    LastName = x.LastName,
                                    RoleId = x.RoleId,
                                    LocationId = x.LocationId,
                                    IsActive = x.IsActive,
                                    CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
                                    CreatedBy = x.CreatedBy,
                                    ModifiedOn = x.ModifiedOn,
                                    ModifiedBy = x.ModifiedBy
                                }).SingleOrDefault();  //_userManager.FindById(changePassword.UserId);

        if (user == null)
        {
            //does not exist
            return 0;
        }

        user.PasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(changePassword.NewPassword);
        var result = _userManager.Update(user);
```

Comment: What are your findings and how they did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont think this question is formatted the right way but ill guess ill answer it anyways.

Hashing is one way so when a user types in a password for the first time you hash it and store in a database. So when a user logs in you hash the input and compare it with the hash value stored in the database.

Change password works exactly the same. Either you do a raw function which checks if the user typed in the existing one as old and then just update with the new password. 
You can also do it by email but thats not what you asked.